# After a release-upgrade apt suggests to remove python2.7 and 3.6

Tags: ubuntu, python, upgrade

After an `update`, `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade`, `dist-release-upgrade`, lots of issues with broken installs, I managed to fix those (apparently) and the upgrade went smooth so far.

Now it's updated, rebooted, but still, any `apt` command suggests me to remove "unused" packages, such as python2.7 and others:

```
bcrelay cmake-data default-libmysqlclient-dev ebtables gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtk2-engines-xfce
  guile-2.0-libs imagemagick-common landscape-common libargon2-0 libart-2.0-2 libasprintf0v5 libavahi-glib1 libbind9-140 libbind9-160 libblas-common libbonobo2-0
  libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-system1.58.0
  libboost-system1.65.1 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcapnp-0.6.1 libcapnp-0.7.0 libcroco3 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdns-export1100 libdns1100 libdns162 libegl1-mesa
  libevent-2.1-6 libfftw3-single3 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-3-common libgdbm3 libgdbm5 libgfortran3 libgfortran4 libglade2-0 libgnome-2-0 libgnome-keyring-common
  libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libhdf5-10 libical1a libical3 libicu60 libilmbase12 libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libirs160 libisc-export169 libisc160 libisc169 libisccc140
  libisccc160 libisccfg140 libisccfg160 libisl19 libjpeg-progs libjpeg9 libjs-async libjson-c3 libjsoncpp1 libjte1 libkeybinder0 libllvm10 libllvm3.8 libllvm5.0
  liblwres141 liblwres160 libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-3 libmirclient9 libmircommon7 libmircore1 libmirprotobuf3
  libmysqlclient-dev libntfs-3g88 libopenexr22 liborbit-2-0 libperl5.26 libplymouth4 libpococrypto50 libpocodata50 libpocodatamysql50 libpocodataodbc50
  libpocodatasqlite50 libpocofoundation50 libpocojson50 libpocomongodb50 libpoconet50 libpoconetssl50 libpocoredis50 libpocoutil50 libpocoxml50 libpocozip50
  libpoppler58 libpoppler73 libprocps6 libprotobuf-lite10 libprotobuf-lite17 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libpython-all-dev libpython2-dev libpython2.7-dev
  libpython3.5-dev libpython3.6 libpython3.6-dev libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libqrencode3 libreadline7 librhash0 libsane1 libsqlite3-dev libssl1.0.2
  libthunarx-2-0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libusbmuxd4 libvte-common libvte9 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwebp5 libwebpmux1 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0 libwnck-common
  libwnck22 libxfconf-0-2 libxfont1 linux-headers-4.4.0-193 linux-headers-4.4.0-193-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-209 linux-headers-4.4.0-209-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-193-generic linux-image-4.4.0-209-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-193-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-209-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-193-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-209-generic mongodb-org-tools nplan orage orage-data python-all python-asn1crypto python-idna
  python2.7-dev python3-appdirs python3-asn1crypto python3-automat python3-click python3-colorama python3-configobj python3-constantly python3-distlib
  python3-filelock python3-hamcrest python3-hyperlink python3-incremental python3-pam python3-pyasn1 python3-pyasn1-modules python3-serial
  python3-service-identity python3-twisted python3-twisted-bin python3-virtualenv python3-xdg python3-zope.interface python3.5-dev python3.6 python3.6-dev
  python3.6-minimal python3.6-venv ttf-dejavu-core virtualenv xdelta3 xfce4-artwork xfce4-mount-plugin xfce4-volumed xscreensaver-data xubuntu-icon-theme
```

I have heard of broken systems after removing Python2.7.

When I run "python3", however, it opens the Python 3.8.10 CLI.

Is it safe to `autoremove` the above packages?

I run Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 20.04, python2.7 has been moved to `universe` repository. The System use python3.8 version (see `python3 -V`), so you can remove it safety.

Comment: Yes, `python3 -V` returns `Python 3.8.10`. So I think I can autoremove, right?

Comment: @Fusseldieb yes you can remove it.

Comment: Strangely, after autoremoving all those packages, running `python` (not `3`) still runs `Python 2.7.18`...

Comment: this is from package `python-is-python2` It creates       /usr/bin/python to the DEPRECATED python2`